# Invalid site in profile allowed?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, hyperlinks

I was taking a look at [this user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1931274/schoolboy), which seems to have a invalid URL for the site:

[image]

Why is this allowed (I believe hyphens are not permitted as the last character in a FQDN) and isn't the scheme (`http://`) meant to be stripped from the link?

[image]

Comment: The url is not linked, it is not clickable. Why should we care about a user entering an invalid URL *at all*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I've seen plenty like this that *are* clickable (like "none"); unless this was fixed very recently the one linked by the OP is an anomaly in its non-linkedness. OTOH, it's the profile owner's problem, trying to validate these would be a waste of programmer effort IMO.

Comment: You *are* the weakest link. Goodbye! </badGameshowReference>

Comment: Who knew that went over to the US... I feel sorry for you @Andrew. The Atlantic normally manages to weed out the majority of the crap in both directions.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - you and I clearly have different TV providers...

Answer (score 8):

It's not actually a link, just text, and by definition isn't a URL.
Even if it was click-able, who cares going to an invalid URL? Your browser would just say invalid URL or cannot find server (depending on what it tried to do with it - auto-complete/guess)

If it went to some spammy site selling crap or illegal stuff, or bogus site trying to gather my data somehow, then I'd be concerned.

You couldn't post that as a genuine link in posts, ie if I try to do this it wont let me post:

```
[Naughty Link][1]
  [1]: http://-
```

The profile page allows you to save `http://-` as a website link, but doesn't actually make it a link as it's invalid. Although it does allow part legitimate URLs to become links, such as:

```
http://no-tld
```

But again, it does no harm as it's not an actual site